# sharepoint server 2019 command bar and items grid broken after CU September 2020 (Only Italian Language)

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, cumulative-update

I installed the CU September 2020 (KB4484504 and KB4484505).
After that, the command bar on libraries and lists and in the items grid are broken.

[image: Command bar not visible]

I created a new site in English language and there the command bar is visible.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug introduced with this CU. Looks like this only happens to localized webs. It is already listed as known issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484505/security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-sept-8-2020

Workaround is to use classic mode at the moment.

As far as I heard, there are already some cases open for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted about the august cu breaking oob menu functionality in SharePoint 2019.In the console I see js errors introduced after the updates. Checkout your chrome dev tools console and i bet you will see some awesome new errors courtesy of microsoft.

Comment: No javascript error is detected by the chrome console. Only an error on ajax request is traced: "{siteUrl}/_api/SP.Directory.DirectorySession/User(principalName='{myDomain/myUsername}')?$select=sharePointLibrariesFirstRun,sharePointFiltersPaneFirstRun 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Answer (score 0):

Install KB 4484504. See the following documentation. This helped me resolve the missing command bar.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4461512/september-21-2020-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-kb4461512

Comment: I already installed it. It works! Thanks!